# Category group ordering within categories tab

Tags: categories

Does anyone know if it's possible to change the order category groups appear within the categories tab when publishing/editing an entry?

Mine are coming back in neither ID order nor alphabetical order!

Comment: just wanted to follow up from our [Twitter dialog](https://twitter.com/nalbuquerque/status/319853600505487361). . Was [Category Field](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/category-field) a good fit for you? If so, let's mark this thread as answered!

Comment: Yes, Category Field did the job nicely. There doesn't seem to be any way to change the category group order otherwise! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no way to do this out of the box, but the [Category Field addon](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/category-field) makes it possible (and is an excellent addon for categories generally!).

Answer (score 1):

Go to to **Admin > Channel Administration > Categories** drop down, then click on **Add/Edit Categories** and choose Alphabetical or Custom sorting. Based on what you said, you probably have custom sorting enabled.

You can also do the custom sort within the actual categories tab like I mention below or do it in the Admin Categories area.

In the Categories tab on the edit/publish entry page, click the **Edit Categories** link underneath the actual categories. The categories have a custom sort order based on that.

There are arrows to move them up or down.

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks, but no - it was the order of the groups I was looking to change, not the actual categories themselves.

Comment: Ahh, Ok. Well good to know something worked out.